# Make dummy variable for categorical data, based on ID column with duplicate values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    ID    value
0   1     A
1   1     B
2   1     C
3   2     B
4   10    C
5   4     C
6   4     A
```

I want to make dummy variables for the values in the column 'value', for each value in the column 'ID'. So I want it this:

```
    ID    A    B    C
0   1     1    1    1
1   2     0    1    0
2   10    0    0    1
3   4     1    0    1
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: `df.assign(dummy=1).pivot_table('dummy', 'ID', 'value', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0).clip(upper=1)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This also works

Comment: @jezrael. You can reopen it if you think it's not just a pivot problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with limit counts to `1` by [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df1  = (pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['value'])
          .clip(upper=1)
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
   ID  A  B  C
0   1  1  1  1
1   2  0  1  0
2   4  1  0  1
3  10  0  0  1
```

Comment: Alternate: `pd.get_dummies(df['value']).groupby(df['ID']).max().reset_index()`, little less typing :p